# Django Form Wizard backup and restore

Tags: python, django, cookies, django-forms, django-formwizard

I have a small problem of understanding and applying a backup and restoration functionality to the form wizard module from Django's contrib libraries.

I tried to create a storage class that uses database to store current status, rather than cookie or session but that didn't solved my case, because when form initializes, all the old data gets cleaned, it's same in both cookie storage and session storage (and mine was imitating cookie one but saves to db)

The issue I need to fill is, if a user left the form in the x.th step (let's say electric went out) and then login again and start the wizard, the user must continue until finishes or clicks 'cancel' (which is not implemented yet too).

Comment: I believe you are storing the forms data yourself, not relying on formwizard. If you can also store the last step for the user, pass initial data for the wizard from the data you stored.

Comment: I rely on form wizard, I got 5 forms and 3 models with foreign keys to eachother. I want to store step datas before .done() so I can restore later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override post method in the view like this:

```
class YourWizardView(SessionWizardView):

    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.get_form(
            data=self.request.POST, files=self.request.FILES)
        data = self.get_all_cleaned_data()
        form.is_valid()  # to generate cleaned data
        data.update(form.cleaned_data)
        #Save your data HERE
        return super(YourWizardView, self).post(*args, **kwargs)
     def get_form_instance(self, step):
        # Getting obj instance values
        obj = None
        if 'pk' in self.kwargs:
            obj = get_object_or_404(
                YourModel, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return self.instance_dict.get(step, obj)
```

If you want the user to return back and see data without clicking next you can do some javascript to post data via ajax (for example every 5 sec)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, overrode post() in a similar fashion. After is_valid check and set_step_[data|files]() functions, I put a small call to a function that saves get_all_cleaned_data() to a temporary_data table. Do you have any idea how can put the data from temporary_data table to form and make it start from where user left?